# rewrite an url with GET parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What rewrite rule in `.htaccess` do I need to rewrite an url in the form

`http://localhost:8080/test/college_details.php?id=[some id]&name=[some name]`

to the form

`http://localhost:8080/test/[some name]/[some id]`

For example, I'd like the URL `http://localhost:8080/test/college_details.php?id=53&name=college-name` to be rewritten to `http://localhost:8080/test/college-name/53`

Comment: try to find a Solution on your own and then show us what you tried so far

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^m3/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ m3/college_details.php?name=com_frontpage&id=$1 [L,QSA] but its not working!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to have a clearer title, included some formatting, and included both the original version as the re-written version of both the abstract version of your question with placeholders and the concrete example. Also, I removed the niceties like introductions, and closing sentences. They don't belong on StackOverflow, and questions shouldn't have them

Comment: Do you want to redirect `http://localhost:8080/test/college_details.php?id=53&name=college-name` to pretty URL as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below rule in test directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ college_details.php?id=$2&name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: its not working, both localhost and server, placed .htaccess file inside the public_html/test

Comment: not showing any errors...
its displaying like http://mydomain.in/test/college_details.php?id=7&name=test%20colleges...

Comment: nah, man you gave me the wrong link you should use link test/college-name/53 and then check if it is working.

Comment: <a href="college_details.php?id=<?php echo $clg_id; ?>&name=<?php echo $name; ?>" class="btn action_button">View Details</a> passing url in anchor tag is any changes in this section?

Comment: First, check if rewritten url is working or not then use new rewritten rule in your link.